# Writing to a file in a specific format using python

Tags: python

I have the following list where I need to write the contents of the list to a file separated by a tab character. I tried printing the list but I see the square brackets also showing up. Is there a better way to write this?

```
list = ['a','b','c']
with open('file','wb') as outfile:
     outfile.write(str(list))
```

I get the output as below.

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

But I need the output as below without the square brackets and also insert tab space between each values of the list.

```
'a'\t'b'\t'c'
```

Comment: `outfile.write(r"\t".join(c for c in list))`

Comment: Also, don't use `list` as a variable name. That is a reserved built in name for Python. Change to something like `lst` instead.

Comment: I notice that you keep the quotes (e.g., `'a'` etc...) Is that intentional?

Comment: Thank you all very much for the varied answers and feedback! @tdelaney, I didn't actually mean to keep the quotes in my final output but having it in my question indirectly helped me in understanding the solutions better.

Answer (score 0):

The method you want is [str.join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join):

```
x = list("abc")  # it's bad practice to shadow the list builtin
print(x)  # not what you want
print("\t".join(x))  # almost there - just missing the single quotes
print("\t".join("'{}'".format(c) for c in x))  # ta-da!
```

Answer (score 0):

The best method depends on what sort of data you have and what if anything may want to read it later. The CSV module deals with things like escaping the separator in a column (suppose the column data itself has a tab), line endings and quoting columns. This may best suite your needs

```
import csv

data = ['a', 'b', 'c']
with open('file', 'w', newline='') as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp, dialect='excel-tab', quotechar="'",
        quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    writer.writerow(data)


# show result...
print(repr(open('file').read()))
```